# php pdo populate html with headers

Tags: php, html, pdo, tableheader

**Using PHP PDO:**
I would like to create and populate html table (thead and tbody) with  information obtained using select statement against mysql database.

All done dynamically providing only basic credentials and table name

Comment: Great idea. What have you got so far?

Comment: Datatables.net provides exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Home brewed solution**

**Firstcreate a connection:**

```
function getConnection1(){
    $dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "test";
$dbpass = "test";
$dbname = "schema name";
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''));
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
return $dbh;
}
```

**Create a function that returns the table:**

```
function retun_html_from_mysql(){

$sql_head = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'schemaname' AND TABLE_NAME = 'table_name';";
$sql_body = "select * from table_name;";

try {
    $db = getConnection1();
    $stmt_head = $db->query($sql_head);
    $stmt_body = $db->query($sql_body);
    $colcount_head = $stmt_head->columnCount();
    $colcount_body = $stmt_body->columnCount();
    $db = null;
    $data =  "<div style='clear: both;'></div>";
    $data .= "<table>";
    $data .= "    <thead>";
    $data .= "        <tr>";
    while ($row = $stmt_head->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM, PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT)) {
        for ($i=0;$i<$colcount_head;$i++){
            $data .= "<th>$row[$i]</th>";
        }
    }
    $data .= "        </tr>";
    $data .= "    </thead>";
    $data .= "    <tbody>";
    while ($row = $stmt_body->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM, PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT)) {
        $data .= "<tr>";
        for ($i=0;$i<$colcount_body;$i++){
            $data .= "<td>$row[$i]</td>";
        }
        $data .= "</tr>";
    }
    $data .= "    </tbody>";
    $data .= "    <tfoot>";
    $data .= "        <tr>";
    for ($i=0; $i<$colcount_head;$i++){
        $data .= "<th></th>";
    }
    $data .= "        </tr>";
    $data .= "    </tfoot>";
    $data .= "</table>";        
    echo $data;

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo '{"error":{"text":' . $e->getMessage() . '}}';
}


}
```

**Happy Coding!**

Comment: Did you answer your own question or is this supposed to be posted in your question?

Comment: I answered my own question, I was missing the header part and I figured it by taking my lunch break, I guess I was hungry :-)